# Django:Error upon having more than than 3 models in one view

Tags: python, django, view, model

am trying to create a dashboard template page having a summary of the system model.But when i exceed more than three models in the view,it shows up an error.How do i go about this?

```
def dashboard(request):

return render(request=request,
            template_name = 'main/admin.html',
            context = {
                    "teachers_list": Teacher.objects.all(),
                    "stream_list": Stream.objects.all(),
                    "fees_list":Fees.objects.all(),
                    "books_list":Book.objects.all()

                }
                )
```

Comment: can you show the error trace?

Comment: paste the error in your question, please.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised the error is from one of the url template a tags